# How to find how many times each value is repeated in generic class list?

Tags: c#, class, generics

I am doing my homework about Generic classes, I have created my data classes Student and Module, and List class List, everything is connected with nodes, I have Node class too, but that is not the case. I need to find how many modules each lecturer has(lecturer can have more than 1 module).
Let's say I have data about module:

```
Module name   Lecturer name 
Math            AAAA
Physics         BBBB
IT              AAAA
```

So I need to find how many modules each lecturer has, because every lecturer can have more than 1 module, so the results should be:

```
AAAA - 2, BBBB - 1
```

Comment: Could you show us your sourcecode? What did you try?

Comment: What did you try so far? How would you learn if we´d give you the solution?

Comment: Look into [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I have tried double cycle, but then I realized, if there is more than 2 modules chosen, it will not work.

Comment: enum is what I was looking for, thanks for help, @ChrisPickford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like something like:

```cs
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => x.LecturerName);
foreach(var grp in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key}: {grp.Count()}");
}
```

should work?

Comment: Yes, it works as well for grouping and for counting, thanks.